# Display complete dependency tree with Leiningen

Tags: clojure, tree, dependencies, leiningen

I understand that `lein deps :tree` displays a dependency tree of all the project dependencies (implicit and explicit). However, "each dependency is only shown once within a tree." I'd really like to see a tree where this wasn't the case, and that if libraries `A` and `B` require library `X`, library `X` shows up under both `A` and `B`.

Does anyone know how to do this with `lein` or some other tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done without Leiningen using [tools.deps](https://clojure.org/reference/deps_and_cli).  With a minimal `deps.edn` file like:

```clj
{:deps {}}
```

Then view the tree with:

```sh
% clj -Stree
org.clojure/clojure 1.10.1
  org.clojure/spec.alpha 0.2.176
  org.clojure/core.specs.alpha 0.2.44
```

Comment: I appreciate the `tools.deps` (which I'm now using) answer, but unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. As with `lein deps :tree`, `clj -Stree` only prints each dep once, and so it's not as useful for determining where there might be a dependency conflict.

Comment: It seems this has changed recently, and now `clj -Stree` *does* print out everything?

Answer (score 45):

You can generate Maven's POM out of Leiningen's project definition and then use Maven's `dependency:tree` plugin with a `verbose` option, like this:

```
$ lein pom
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true
```

This will list dependencies omitted for various reasons, e.g.:

```
|  +- ring:ring-core:jar:1.4.0:compile
|  |  +- (org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.5.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.0)
|  |  +- (org.clojure:tools.reader:jar:0.9.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.10.0-alpha3)
|  |  +- (ring:ring-codec:jar:1.0.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

For more options to `dependency:tree` see its [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html).

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks.

For those who don't have access to `mvn`, you can run `sudo apt-get install maven` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 39):

This can now be done using **leiningen** by `lein deps :tree`. Note the space between *deps* and *:tree*.

Comment: At the time of writing, this command doesn't show an actual tree. It uses indentation to indicate dependencies, which makes it a pain to read.

Comment: The OP mentions that they are using `lein deps :tree` already.

Comment: PLEASE STOP VOTING FOR THIS ANSWER!!!

The author seems to have barely read my post, as I stand by saying "I understand that `lein deps :tree` ...". This answer does not solve the problem.